# Binomial summation without coefficient

Tags: summation

I have the following summation:

$$\sum_{i=0}^na^{n-i}b^i$$

I recognise that if the binomial coefficient was present, it would represent the expansion of $(a+b)^n$.  However, since that coefficient is absent, I am struggling to find a formulaic representation of the summation: does one exist?

Comment: Try geometric series with $q=b/a$.

Comment: Multiply your sum with $(a-b)$, and see what you get... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{a^2-b^2}{a-b}\quad &=a+b,\\
\frac{a^3-b^3}{a-b}\quad &=a^2+ab+b^2,\\
\ldots & \\
\frac{a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}}{a-b}&=\; ?\;
\end{align}