# How to sum this quasi-binomial summation without coefficients?

Tags: summation

I have the summation
$$\sum_{k =1}^{n + 2}x^{n + 2 -k}y^k$$

which expands out to (taking $n = 3$ as an example)

$$x^4y^1 + x^3y^2 + x^2y^3 + x^1y^4.$$

How can I sum it? It looks similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/830468/binomial-summation-without-coefficient) but the indices cannot be shifted to match that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a finite geometric sum with common ratio $y/x$. In general a finite geometric sum with common ratio $r \neq 1$ is "first term - first omitted term" divided by $1-r$, so in your case the result is $\frac{x^{n+1} y - x^{-1} y^{n+3}}{1-(y/x)}$ unless $y/x=1$.